# Make implicit rules and header files

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

Make's implicit rules are supposedly there to make writing Makefiles easier but, if my understanding is correct, if my C files depend on any header files, I need to write the rule, explicitly. Am I right? This seems to serioiusly lower the usefulness of implicit rules, since most C files depend on a couple of header files, so I thought perhaps there's something I'm missing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9598716/412080

Comment: Ah! I swear I searched Google and StackOverflow for like half an hour and couldn't find that one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to write the rule, only the dependencies. Example:

```
foo.o : foo.h bar.h
```

The file foo.o will still be generated by the implicit rule, but have the additional dependencies `foo.h` and `bar.h`. This dependency line can also be auto-generated by most compilers.

Comment: Thank you. This lowers the burden at least! By the way, I've never heard about compilers writing Makefiles. How does that work? I use gcc 4.7.0.

Comment: @Homaymoon: Look at e.g. the `-M` flag for GCC (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Comment: Thanks. -M seems to be a little difficult to use though, at least in slightly complicated projects. I need to give it all the cflags that I usually put in the Makefile and forget about. Also, even when using -MM, it produces all the glib headers in its output, perhaps because I had to add $(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0) to the gcc line.

Comment: @Homayoon: It's not trivial to write auto-dependency makefiles. Using `automake` is a common remedy, these people have figured it out once and for all.

Answer (score 8):

You can autogenerate header dependencies with gcc using the following makefile snippet

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
DEPS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.d)
CFLAGS += -MMD

-include $(DEPS)
```

The code might need some adjustments to work with your particular ruleset.

Answer (score 2):

`make` is **not** a utility which goes and reads inside your C file and determines which header it is including. It works based on changed timestamps of files. Hence, irrespective of whether a target is dependent on a header or any other file, you need to explicitly tell `make` of the dependencies.

`gcc` can help you ease your job by generating a dependency list for you like this

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"my_header.h"

int main ()
{
return 0;
}
```

And then,

```
gcc -M main.c
```

Now, with `-M` preprocessor flag, it will automatically generate a dependency list like

```
main.o: main.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/features.h \
 /usr/include/bits/predefs.h /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/bits/types.h /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/libio.h /usr/include/_G_config.h /usr/include/wchar.h \
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/bits/stdio_lim.h /usr/include/bits/sys_errlist.h \
 my_header.h
```

`gcc` has figured out all includes inside `stdio.h` too!