# how Makefiles work exactly

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a code for my gtk application written in C, and have some questions about it.

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -o
RM = rm -f

# ADDITIONAL HEADER PATH 
GTKINC = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
GTKLIB = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` 

INC = $(GTKINC)
LIBLNK = $(GTKLIB)


# SOURCES, OBJECTS, EXECUTABLE
SRCS = hello.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c = .o)
EXEC = hello

.PHONY: clean

all: $(EXEC)
    @echo compile complete 

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LIBLNK)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(EXEC)
```

previously, when I wrote Makefiles,I added lines for each object files

for example

```
blah blah

a.o: 1.h A.c B.c
        $(CC) blah blah
blah blah
```

and then, I got a little lazy and tried to do make something more easy-to-modify file
googling up, and finally the product is the above code. 
1. Does this actually do the same thing as what I did previously?(like in the example)
I found out the code compiles properly, but I'm not sure if it checks out-of-date
object files.(which is the whole meaning of 'make')
2. do you **have to** use 'depend' on header files in order to check out-of-date source files??
3. it's a bit out of subject, but what's the difference between
gcc -o hello.o hello.h hello.c and
gcc -c hello.c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `2.` do you have to use 'depend' on header files in order to check out-of-date source files

You should auto-generate dependencies on header files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598716/412080

Comment: I think your answer to #1 is not correct.  ksp0422 is showing the method used to compile object files in the previous makefile.  Presumably there was also a similar linker line, which is not shown.  So he's not comparing compiling to linking.  In the new makefile he's relying on make's builtin rules to compile, while in the old makefile he created explicit compile rules for each object.