# Makefile .cpp.o: vs %o: %.cpp

Tags: makefile

In make, what is the difference between:

```
%.o: %.cpp foolib.h
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

and

```
.cpp.o: foolib.h
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

?

Also, am I right in understanding that `foolib.h` should be included in the rules as shown above if the changes made in the header are to be (re)compiled even when there is no change in the .cpp files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cpp.o:` syntax is [Old-Fashioned Suffix Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules).

> Am I right in understanding that foolib.h should be included in the rules as shown above if the changes made in the header are to be (re)compiled even when there is no change in the .cpp files?

You are right. However, maintaining header dependencies this way is tedious and error-prone. People normally use [auto-generated header dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598716/412080).