# makefile not compiling changed main program file

Tags: makefile

```
ALLSRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OTHERSRCS := testRWdata.c testddb.c testsuite.c driver.c DumpAFile.c testavl.c tester.c
SRCS := $(filter-out $(OTHERSRCS),$(ALLSRCS))
OBJS := $(addprefix obj/,$(SRCS:.c=.o))
PROGS = testRWdata testddb testsuite driver DumpAFile testavl tester


OTHER_LIBS = 
OTHER_PRODUCT_DEPENDS = buffer.h dbinfo.h avl.h
TEST_OUT = nextdb.test.out
DATA_FILES = test.dfd test.input.test test.input.full test.input tstavl.input $(TEST_OUT) 
HELP_FILES = README
OTHER_GARBAGE = test.asc test.dat test.wrk test.log test.dump

.PHONY: all clean

doall : $(PROGS)

obj/%.o: %.c | obj 
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p $@

testsuite: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $@.c
    -chmod a+x $@
```

make testsuite works IF the obj directory is empty or one of the files included in OBJS.  After doing this once, then editing the file
testsuite.c, make testsuite  says that there are no changes.  How to make the file detect that testsuite.c was changed or that one of the .h files was changed?

Comment: This is not related to the C language.

Comment: By inspection, you filter `testsuite.c` out of `SRCS`, which means that `testsuite.o` is not in `OBJS`, which means that it is not a prerequisite of `testsuite`, so Make doesn't care about it. I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: I have several such files that have main functions. If I don't filter them out, I get errors about multiple main programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testsuite` must depend on `testsuite.o` or `testsuite.c`. Possible fix:

```
testsuite: obj/testsuite.o $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Note that `chmod` is unnecessary, the produced executable is, well, executable.

You may also like to [generate header dependencies automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598716/412080).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, here's an example I made for your specific case [[full code]](https://github.com/TermanEmil/makefile_stackoverflow_answer).

As far as I understood, you have a main.c file, which is your main for the main program. You also have some test.c files, which contains other mains. And you have other source files, which I call SHARED_SRC which do not contain .c files with main-s in them. These SHARED_SRC files are used to compile both the main program and the tests.

To run this makefile, run `make` and `make tests`.

To recompile when a header file is modified, I simply added:
`obj/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` - to the rule for each .o object

I created separate rules for the tests. Note: the test file names have to start with "test" prefix.

I hope it answered your question.

Edit: added the whole example here.

Makefile:

```
#We suppose that the program with the main main function is in main.c

NAME        =   JWooten

ALLSRCS     :=  $(wildcard *.c)
OTHERSRCS   :=  testMain1.c testMain2.c
SHARED_SRC  :=  $(filter-out main.c $(OTHERSRCS),$(ALLSRCS))

ALL_OBJS    :=  $(addprefix obj/,$(ALLSRCS:.c=.o))
SHARED_OBJS :=  $(addprefix obj/,$(SHARED_SRC:.c=.o))
OTHER_OBJS  :=  $(addprefix obj/,$(OTHERSRCS:.c=.o))
MAIN_OBJ    :=  obj/main.o

TEST_NAMES  :=  $(OTHERSRCS:.c=)

HEADERS     :=  $(wildcard *.h)

all: $(NAME)


#Adding the $(HEADERS) to the rule, makes it recompile the object whenever the
#header is modified
obj/%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c $< -o $@

#Rules for the tests.
test%: test%.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc $(SHARED_OBJS) obj/$@.o -o $@
    -chmod a+x $@

make_obj_dir:
    @mkdir -p obj

#Rule to make the tests
tests: make_obj_dir $(SHARED_OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS) $(TEST_NAMES)

$(NAME): make_obj_dir $(SHARED_OBJS) $(MAIN_OBJ)
    gcc $(SHARED_OBJS) $(MAIN_OBJ) -o $(NAME)
    -chmod a+x $(NAME)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -rf obj

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(TEST_NAMES)
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

main.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int     main(void)
{
    some_function1();
    some_function2();
    return (0);
}
```

file1.c

```
#include "header.h"

void    some_function1(void)
{
    printf("Function 1\n");
}
```

file2.c

```
#include "header.h"

void    some_function2(void)
{
    printf("Function 2\n");
}
```

testMain1.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int     main(void)
{
    some_function1();
    return (0); 
}
```

testMain2.c:

```
#include "header.h"

int     main(void)
{
    some_function2();
    return (0); 
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
# define HEADER_H

# include <stdio.h>

void    some_function1(void);
void    some_function2(void);

#endif
```

Comment: This was EXCELLENT.  I was able to follow it and your comments.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I made a fully working example. If it was about simple coding, I would've posted it in the answer, but since it's a makefile - I thought the best way would be to give a fully working mini project